# Akka streams ignore onComplete event on ActorSubscriber

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I have a use-case where I have a fixed number of elements flowing in from a source. These elements get processed and then there is a Sink which is an ActorSubscriber in our case. What happens is the Source signals an complete event after sending all the elements. This event gets propagated to the Sink and the sink fires the onComplete event and closes the stream workflow. All this happens while the elements are still being processed in the intermediate step.

Once the processing completes when the intermediate step returns processed data, it doesn't find a subscriber since it has already closed due to the onComplete event being triggered. Is there a way we can discard the onComplete event on the actor subscriber and keep it open always.

Code Snippets:

```
val sample1 = //Sample time series

Source(List(sample1,sample2,sample3))
    .map(m => akka.util.ByteString( m.getBytes ))
    .to(detectionWorkflow(context))
    .run()

 val intakeBuffer = b.add(
    Flow[ByteString]
      .buffer(conf.tcpInboundBufferSize, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  )

  val timeSeries = b.add(
    Flow[ByteString]
    .via( watch("unpacking") )
    .via( unmarshalTimeSeriesData )
    .via( watch("unpacked") )
  )

  val scoring = b.add(
   OutlierScoringModel.scoringGraph(planRouterRef = context.planRouter, config = conf)
  )

 intakeBuffer ~> timeSeries ~> scoring.in
                                scoring.out0 /*~> publishBuffer*/  ~> Sink.actorSubscriber(SpotlightSubscriber.props)
                                scoring.out1 ~> logUnrecognized ~> termUnrecognized
```

Actor Subscriber:

```
class SpotlightSubscriber extends ActorSubscriber with ActorLogging {
protected val logger: Logger = Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger("SpotlightSubscriber"))
 protected def requestStrategy = WatermarkRequestStrategy(1)
def receive = {
case OnNext(outlier: Outliers) =>
  log.debug("[SpotlightSubscriber] Received : {}", outlier)
case OnError(err: Exception) =>
  log.error(err, "[SpotlightSubscriber] Received Exception in Spotlight Stream")
  context.stop(self)
case OnComplete =>
  log.info("[SpotlightSubscriber] Spotlight Stream Completed!")
  context.stop(self)
case _ => }}
```

Scoring does the processing work. What is happening is the source which has 3 elements sends the complete event to the sink. The actorSubscriber's onComplete event is triggered once it receives the complete event from the source. After processing the scoring engine sends the processed results back to the actorSubscriber, but as its not active anymore, we get deadLetter messages.

Comment: Can you show us some code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: @thwiegan Updated with some relevant code fragments.